# Adding XML attribute from array PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I am have a dynamic HTML form (jQuery) that a user can add in an ingredient and its quantity, After the user puts in the data I need to save the data as XML. I was thinking of having the quantity as an attribute of the ingredient tag, so for example

```
<ingredient quantity="250g"> spaghetti </ingredient>
```

However at the moment I'm not sure how to pass the information in through my array as only a string is allowed as an attribute. I was wondering if anyone had an idea how to do this?

Here are some snippets of my code.

HTML form:

```
<div id="addIngredient">
            <p>
            <input type="text" id="ingredient_1" name="ingredient[]" value="" placeholder="Ingredient"/>
            <input type="text" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]"  value="" placeholder="quantity"/>
            <a href="#" id="addNewIngredient">Add</a>
            </p>
            </div>
            <br />
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
    $('<p> <input id="ingredient_' + i + '" size="40" name="ingredient[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Ingredient" /><input id="quantity_' + i + '" size="40" name="quantity[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" /><a href=#" class="remNew2"> Remove </a> </p> ').appendTo(addDiv2);
    i++;
    return false;

    });
```

PHP:

```
$ingredients = $xml->createElement('ingredients');
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
            $element = $ingredientName[$i];
            $ingredient = $xml->createElement('ingredient_name', $element);
            $ingredient->setAttribute("quantity", $quantity);
            $ingredients->appendChild($ingredient);
        }
        $recipe->appendChild($ingredients);
```

Comment: Are you looking how to populate `$quantity` and `$ingredient`?

Comment: i can populate them, i need to be able to save the quantity as each ingrediants attribute